# How to remove a specific string common in multiple lines in a CSV file using python script?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a csv file which contains 65000 lines (Size approximately 28 MB). In each of the lines a certain path in the beginning is given e.g. `"c:\abc\bcd\def\123\456"`. Now let's say the path `"c:\abc\bcd\"` is common in all the lines and rest of the content is different. I have to remove the common part (In this case `"c:\abc\bcd\"`) from all the lines using a python script. For example the content of the CSV file is as mentioned.

```
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.frag                   0   0   0
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.vert                   0   0   0
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.frag       16  24  3
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.vert       87  116 69
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin   75  95  61
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0            0   0
C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-6            0   0   0
```

In the above example I need the output as below

```
FILE0.frag                  0   0   0
FILE0.vert                  0   0   0
FILE0.link-link-0.frag      17  25  2
FILE0.link-link-0.vert      85  111 68
FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin  77  97  60
FILE0.link-link-0               0   0
FILE0.link                  0   0   0
```

Can any of you please help me out with this?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: What about removing all chars upto the last backslash?

Comment: it is not clear from the question if the "common" part, is to be autodetected?

Comment: Hi Avinash. Thanks for the response. I am new to python and trying to understand how does python work on file handling. Since this operation has to performed on multiple files in a directory and sub-directories, I am using os.walk for this.

Comment: Henrik, How about if we store the common part in some variable, Because it's going to be same all the time ?

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, it's a good idea to mark that answer as accepted so it can help other with a question similar to yours.

Comment: Hi Alok, I am still working on it and trying different answers. Will mark the answer as accepted once i am done. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried something like this

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(Directory):
    for fname in fileList:
        if fname.endswith('.csv'):
            for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(dirName, fname), inplace = 1):
                location = line.find(r'GLNext')
                if location > 0:
                    location += len('GLNext')
                    print line.replace(line[:location], ".")
                else:
                    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like,

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", 'rb') as f:
    sl = []
    csvread = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for line in csvread:
        sl.append(line.replace("C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\", ""))
```

To write the list `sl` out to `filenew` use,

```
with open('filenew.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csvwrite = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for line in sl:
        csvwrite.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ed. Will it save the file as well ?

Comment: You will have a list of the new strings in sl. need to call a write. If your file is csv (with separator, not like the data you have above) then you should use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\S+/
```

You can simply use this regex over each line and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/17

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^\S+/', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.frag                   0   0   0\nC:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.vert                   0   0   0\nC:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.frag       16  24  3\nC:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.vert       87  116 69\nC:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin   75  95  61\nC:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0            0   0\nC:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-6            0   0   0 "
subst = u" "

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically detect the common prefix without the need to hardcode it. You don't really need `regex` for this. `os.path.commonprefix` can be used 
instead:

```
import csv
import os

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    paths = [] #stores all paths
    rows = [] #stores all lines
    for row in reader:
        paths.append(row[0].split("/")) #split path by "/"
        rows.append(row)

    commonprefix = os.path.commonprefix(paths) #finds prefix common to all paths

    for row in rows:
        row[0] = row[0].replace('/'.join(commonprefix)+'/', "") #remove prefix
```

`rows` now has a list of lists which you can write to a file

```
with open('data2.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python script will read your file in (assuming it looks like your example) and will create a version removing the common folders:

```
import os.path, csv

finput = open("d:\\input.csv","r")
csv_input = csv.reader(finput, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
csv_output = csv.writer(open("d:\\output.csv", "wb"), delimiter=" ")

# Create a set of unique folder names

set_folders = set()

for input_row in csv_input:
    set_folders.add(os.path.split(input_row[0])[0])

# Determine the common prefix

base_folder = os.path.split(os.path.commonprefix(set_folders))[0]
nprefix = len(base_folder) + 1

# Go back to the start of the input CSV 

finput.seek(0)

for input_row in csv_input:
    csv_output.writerow([input_row[0][nprefix:]] + input_row[1:])
```

Using the following as input:

```
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.frag                   0   0   0
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.vert                   0   0   0
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.frag       16  24  3
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext2/FILE0.link-link-0.vert       87  116 69
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext5/FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin   75  95  61
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext7/FILE0.link-link-0            0   0
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.link-link-6            0   0   0
```

The output is as follows:

```
GLNext/FILE0.frag 0 0 0
GLNext/FILE0.vert 0 0 0
GLNext/FILE0.link-link-0.frag 16 24 3
GLNext2/FILE0.link-link-0.vert 87 116 69
GLNext5/FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin 75 95 61
GLNext7/FILE0.link-link-0 0 0
GLNext/FILE0.link-link-6 0 0 0
```

With one space between each column, although this could easily be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas` library for this. Doing so, you can leverage `pandas`' amazing handling of big CSV files (even in the hundreds of MB).

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = 'test_csv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None)
print df
print "-------------------------------------------"

path = "C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/"
df[0] = df[0].replace({path:""}, regex=True)

print df
# df.to_csv("truncated.csv") # Export to new file.
```

**Result:**

```
                                                   0   1    2   3
0    C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.frag   0    0   0
1    C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.vert   0    0   0
2  C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.lin...  16   24   3
3  C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.lin...  87  116  69
4  C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.lin...  75   95  61
5  C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.lin...   0    0 NaN
6  C:/Abc/bcd/Def/Test/temp/test/GLNext/FILE0.lin...   0    0   0
-------------------------------------------
                            0   1    2   3
0                  FILE0.frag   0    0   0
1                  FILE0.vert   0    0   0
2      FILE0.link-link-0.frag  16   24   3
3      FILE0.link-link-0.vert  87  116  69
4  FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin  75   95  61
5           FILE0.link-link-0   0    0 NaN
6           FILE0.link-link-6   0    0   0
```